# SQL replace all columns with the same 2xstring

Tags: sql, replace

I want to replace all columns with the same string twice, for example

```
string1 : string1string1
string2 : string2string2
string3 : string3string3
string4 : string4string4
```

I only know the basic replace:

```
update table set column = replace(column,"oldstring","newstring");
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: update table set coloumn =concat(coloumn,coloumn)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your database one of these queries should work:

```
update table set column =  concat(column,column);
```

or

```
update table set column =  column || column;
```

Comment: column + column works too in MSSQL, concat() is probably most universal

Answer (score 1):

You just need to concatenate the column with itself.

```
UPDATE <table> SET <column> = <column> || <column>;
```